# Probability that an outcome is fair

Tags: probability

I have a program which has 3 slots, each that are supposed to output 0 or 1 with 50% probability, so `[x] [x] [x]`, where `x = 0 or 1`

I think then the probability of all 1's would be 1/(2*2*2)= 1/8, or 12.5%.

If I run this program many times and empirically find that this outcome occurs 20% of the time instead, how do I calculate the probability that the outcome was actually fair according to the model and not tampered with?

Comment: Use Bayes' formula.

Comment: That will depend on the (prior) probability of tampering.  If tampering is very unlikely, then even an unlikely distribution of results may still be most likely fair.  If, however, tampering is considered likely to begin with, less likely results will be more likely to imply tampering has taken place.  If you know this prior probability of tampering, Lovsos is correct that you can use Bayes' formula to determine the probability that tampering has taken place given a particular empirical result.

Comment: hmm makes sense, but what if I don't know the probability of tampering? Should I just give it a value of 50%?

Comment: Do you actually think there's a 50% chance the program will be tampered with (before looking at the results)?  If you don't know the prior probability, just give it your best educated guess.  Btw, In order to use Bayes' Theorem, you also have to know the probability of a given outcome if Tampering *has* taken place.  If the form of tampering in question is deterministic, this may be $1$, if however, it is probabilistic, then it may be something else.

Comment: If you run your program $n$ times, with $n\ge30$ and $np>5$ (here $p=\frac18$), the probability that the outcome of 111 will be between $p-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and $p+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ should be greater than $95\%$. So your result is OK for $n=100$, not OK for $n=1000$...

Comment: Is there a way to write the likelihood in probability of 20% outcome for n = 1000? Sorry been a long time since I've done any probability.

Comment: @Jake do you mean the probability of getting at least 200 "111" results in 1000 iterations? or exactly 200? In any case the probability (if all results are in fact equally likely) is $$\frac {\text{# of possible favorable results}} {\text{total # of possible results}}$$ So for exactly $k$ "111"'s in $n$ trials the probability is $$\frac {n \choose k} {8^n}$$ and for at least $k$ "111"s it's $$\sum_{i\ge k} \frac {n \choose i} {8^n}$$

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS 95% confidence is a common bar to set, for sure, but his question isn't about statistical significance, it's about whether or not his process was tampered with.  Results will fall outside of the 95% confidence interval naturally 1/20 of the time, and if the probability of tampering is lower than 1/41, then such results are still most likely to the output of an unmolested system.  However, if as he suggested the probability of tampering is 50% then even some results in that 95% interval could be suspect, depending on the nature of the tampering.